# Problem with Android Networking (Using Google Book API and LoadManager/ AsyncTaskLoader)

Tags: java, android

Having problems debugging an android networking application. I think I might have some problems with the import but I don't know which. If you can see the problem, please do let me know. Thank you.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.networkingfinals;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<List<BookInfo>> {

    private String url;
    private String input;
    private BookAdapter bookAdapter;
    private int LOADER_ID = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
                input = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
                url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+input+"&maxResults=3";
            }
        });
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);//Set loader manager to call asyncloader in onCreateLoader
        //TODO: Implement AsyncTaskLoader and LoadManager fetching network data on parallel thread



    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<BookInfo>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        Loader<List<BookInfo>> books = new BookAsync(this, url);

        return books;

        //Call oncreate Loader , fetching List of Book Info

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookInfo>> loader, List<BookInfo> data) {
        Log.v("onLoadFinished", "Return " + data);
        bookAdapter.addAll(data);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        bookAdapter.clear();

    }
```

Logcat

```
2021-01-10 18:44:55.950 13590-13590/com.example.networkingfinals V/onCreateLoader: Return BookAsync{814c192 id=0}
2021-01-10 18:44:56.045 13590-13590/com.example.networkingfinals V/onLoadFinished: Return null
2021-01-10 18:44:56.045 13590-13590/com.example.networkingfinals D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-01-10 18:44:56.055 13590-13590/com.example.networkingfinals E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.networkingfinals, PID: 13590
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.networkingfinals.BookAdapter.addAll(java.util.Collection)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.networkingfinals.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:61)
        at com.example.networkingfinals.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:497)
        at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:465)
        at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:157)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:274)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:97)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7458)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
2021-01-10 18:44:56.138 13590-13590/com.example.networkingfinals I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13590 SIG:
```

I think I don't understand how onCreateLoader() and onLoadFinished() works. I tried and find that onCreateLoader return non-null data but in onLoadFinished() the data passed into it was null.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your adapter is not initialized yet you need to initialize it in onCreate

```java
this.bookAdapter = new BookAdapter();
```

the error message says

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.networkingfinals.BookAdapter.addAll(java.util.Collection)' on a null object reference
```

that means is your adapter is null and you call addAll from the null object reference

Comment: Thanks AmrDeveloper. I tried changing the adapter but it was a mess so I switched to simply print the output directly in the UI. still working on it